# Problem with adding strings to proper positions of an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am working to make an Instagram type project where you can follow up to five people. For my follow method I tried to loop through a string array (length 5) and say if 'user getting followed' isn't on the list of followers, add that person to the array. But when I do instead of displaying the array like this (when I call the Arrays.toString()):

follows: [user 1, user 2, user 3, user 4, user 5]

It displays the array like this:
follows: [user1user2user3user4user5, , , , ]

Here is my code I am talking about:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if(...) {
    this.following[i] += gettingFollowed.getHandle();

/* getHandle() gets the name of the user getting followed and adds it to the string array, 'following' */
```

Comment: why not just include your code? Difficult to debug the issue if it had been caused by `if(...)` some code you omiitted

Comment: Please add the section of the code for getHandle(). Need to see the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.following[i] += gettingFollowed.getHandle();`

The `+=` instruction *appends* to a String - which is why you are seeing your output. You are appending all your users to the same index.

`this.following[i] = gettingFollowed.getHandle();`

Simply remove the '+' and you are now *setting* the value.

**Still, without knowing what .getHandle() does - this might not completely fix your code.**